# Parse CIL code with Regex

Tags: c#, regex, cil

I have a *.il file. I want to find all non-empty methods in it (.method). For example:

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit MyApp.Program
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
   //catch its body
  .method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
  {
    .entrypoint
    // 
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ret
  }  

  //catch its body
  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  ret
  }  

   //don't touch, it's empty
   .method public hidebysig newslot virtual 
          instance string  Invoke(string a) runtime managed
  {
  }  
 //......................................
}
```

Now I'm doing that using class string. It's quite nonrational. I tried using `Regex` but I could not figure out how to create a reg expression to catch only

- methods (and not classes)
- only methods with non-empty body

Does anybody can help me?

Comment: parsing CIL code with regex can become tricky very fast. What about using something Mono.Cecil where testing for an empty method body is as easy as writing `method.HasBody`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using regex for parsing structure code is not recommended and it is bad practice

Try to use regex pattern

```
(\.method\s[^{]+?)(?=\s*{)(?!\s*{\s*})
```

Test it [**here**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%5C.method%5Cs%5B%5E%7B%5D%2b?%29%28?=%5Cs%2a%7B%29%28?!%5Cs%2a%7B%5Cs%2a%7D%29&input=.class%20private%20auto%20ansi%20beforefieldinit%20MyApp.Program%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20extends%20%5Bmscorlib%5DSystem.Object%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20//catch%20its%20body%0A%20%20.method%20private%20hidebysig%20static%20void%20%20Main%28string%5B%5D%20args%29%20cil%20managed%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20.entrypoint%0A%20%20%20%20//%20%0A%20%20%20%20.maxstack%20%208%0A%20%20%20%20IL_0000%3a%20%20nop%0A%20%20%20%20IL_0001%3a%20%20ret%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%0A%0A%20%20//catch%20its%20body%0A%20%20.method%20public%20hidebysig%20specialname%20rtspecialname%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20instance%20void%20%20.ctor%28%29%20cil%20managed%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20//%20%0A%20%20%20%20.maxstack%20%208%0A%20%20%20%20IL_0000%3a%20%20ldarg.0%0A%20%20%20%20IL_0001%3a%20%20call%20%20%20%20%20%20%20instance%20void%20%5Bmscorlib%5DSystem.Object%3a%3a.ctor%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20IL_0006%3a%20%20ret%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%0A%0A%20%20%20//don%27t%20touch,%20it%27s%20empty%0A%20%20%20.method%20public%20hidebysig%20newslot%20virtual%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20instance%20string%20%20Invoke%28string%20a%29%20runtime%20managed%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%0A%20//......................................%0A%7D).

To catch also the body `{...}` of each method, use regex pattern

```
(\.method\s[^{]+{(?!\s*}).*?})
```

Test it **[here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gs&regex=%28%5C.method%5Cs%5B%5E%7B%5D%2b%7B%28?!%5Cs%2a%7D%29.%2a?%7D%29&input=.class%20private%20auto%20ansi%20beforefieldinit%20MyApp.Program%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20extends%20%5Bmscorlib%5DSystem.Object%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20//catch%20its%20body%0A%20%20.method%20private%20hidebysig%20static%20void%20%20Main%28string%5B%5D%20args%29%20cil%20managed%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20.entrypoint%0A%20%20%20%20//%20%0A%20%20%20%20.maxstack%20%208%0A%20%20%20%20IL_0000%3a%20%20nop%0A%20%20%20%20IL_0001%3a%20%20ret%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%0A%0A%20%20//catch%20its%20body%0A%20%20.method%20public%20hidebysig%20specialname%20rtspecialname%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20instance%20void%20%20.ctor%28%29%20cil%20managed%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20//%20%0A%20%20%20%20.maxstack%20%208%0A%20%20%20%20IL_0000%3a%20%20ldarg.0%0A%20%20%20%20IL_0001%3a%20%20call%20%20%20%20%20%20%20instance%20void%20%5Bmscorlib%5DSystem.Object%3a%3a.ctor%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20IL_0006%3a%20%20ret%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%0A%0A%20%20%20//don%27t%20touch,%20it%27s%20empty%0A%20%20%20.method%20public%20hidebysig%20newslot%20virtual%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20instance%20string%20%20Invoke%28string%20a%29%20runtime%20managed%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%0A%20//......................................%0A%7D)**.

---

To learn more about regular expressions visit [**regular-expressions.info**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: @AlanDert - Answer has been updated :: see **Test it here** link

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working. However, why are you using JavaScript regex tester, is this as the same as C#? And sorry, I forgot to ask, how do I change it find all **bodies** (between { ... }) of these methods (non-empty)? And please explain, what does each part of this regex mean?

Comment: @AlanDert - Answer has been updated with solution that catch the body of the method as well. As a test link I used a JavaScript tester, as I don't know about any free online c# regex tester. If you do, I will be glad to use it, just let me know...

Comment: @AlanDert - Did you use flag `RegexOptions.Singleline` ?

Comment: The last question. Please tell me, how do I catch only the **bodies** (**between** { ... }) of non-empty methods?

Comment: -1: You can't use regular expressions for this, and by giving this answer, you've prompted him to ask [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13004518/197788) about how to deal with the obvious difficulty of nested structures.

Comment: Omega, please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004518/parse-code-with-regex-how-to-capture-methods-body-with-extra